# In mobile friendly test api I am getting API Key not found, Please pass a valid API key error

Tags: curl, google-api

I am trying to provide mobile friendly test option in my website. For this I am testing whether the path is valid or not?

Following is the curl command I ran in Mac OS Terminal.

> curl -H 'Content-Type: application/json' --data '{url:
>   "https://www.some-site.in"}'
>   'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx'

But I am getting following error:

> {   "error": {
>       "code": 400,
>       "message": "API Key not found. Please pass a valid API key.",
>       "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help",
>           "links": [
>             {
>               "description": "Google developer console API key",
>               "url": "https://console.developers.google.com/project/xxxxxxxxxx/apiui/credential"
>             }
>           ]
>         }
>       ]   } }

Note: I have replaced api key and project id with xxxxx...

In Google Developer console, I have created a project, then I have created a api key, I have restricted the api key with my computers ip address inside the developer console. And also I tried with another api key with out restrict key.

But in all case the same above error is appearing.

I have also tried with PHP script and curl method and got 400 error. I have also tried with ajax and got above same error.

I could not able to find what exactly going wrong. Please guide me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the API in "APIs and Services" -> "Library" in order to use API key.

Comment: Add this as comment

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `Google Search Console URL Testing Tools API` under  "APIs and Services" -> "Library"

And then pass the key as  a param (not in the post body, the example on their website didnt work for me)
This worked:

```
api_key="YOUR_KEY"
import requests
request_url = 'https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html'
service_url = f'https://searchconsole.googleapis.com/v1/urlTestingTools/mobileFriendlyTest:run?key={api_key}'
params = {
    'url': request_url,
}

print(requests.post(service_url, json=params).json())
```